# next comment id number wordpress

Tags: database, mysql

I have removed many spam comments from my very old blog (over 3500 spam comments) and purged from the database.
Last comment ID was 3620 after removal latest comment has ID 853.

New added comment should now have ID: 854 but it has ID: 3621.
Is it possible to change it and reuse old IDs ? I looked in wp_options table but I have not found any settings associated with it. Where is it saved in the database? How to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup your comments table first. If you're only dealing with comments marked as spam by Akismet, Akismet sets a WordPress cron to clean up the comment meta table so you don't have to worry about that table.

[Check this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql)

I would go into PHPMyAdmin, select the comments table and run this query:

ALTER TABLE your_comments_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 854